# With PHP, is it possible to merge an animated gif with a jpg and retain the gifs animation?

Tags: php, imagemagick, gd, animated-gif

Using PHP (GD or ImageMagick) I want to merge an animated gif with a jpg and retain the animation of the gif, the product being an animated gif.

In other words, I've got an animated gif that is 500px x 30px and needs to lay on top of a jpg thats 500px x 500px, the end result being a single animated gif.

So again, anyone know if it's possible to merge an animated gif with a jpg and retain the gifs animation?

Comment: Does this need to be done dynamically or is this a one time thing?

Comment: This will surely require you to separate all frames from your animation, then apply the JPG on top of each frame, and after that, you'll have to rebuild your GIF.

Comment: For what purpose are you needing to do this? What function does this need to be able to serve?

Comment: Since you can manupulate files byte by byte, and the file formats of both GIF and Jpeg are known, yes, you can. Will it be easy? No. Is it wise to do so? No, the gif file only had 256 colors at most, so you may loose color depth in the Jpeg file. Also, the Gif image will become much, much larger.

Answer (score 1):

Look [Imagick::animateImages method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-animateimages.php), gomadurai sample:

```
<?php

$multiTIFF = new Imagick();

$mytifspath = "./man"; // your image directory

$files = scandir($mytifspath);

//print_r($files);

/*foreach( $files as $f )
{*/

for($i=2;$i<6;$i++)
{
    echo $files[$i];

    echo "<br>";
    $auxIMG = new Imagick();
    $auxIMG->readImage($mytifspath."/".$files[$i]);

    $multiTIFF->addImage($auxIMG);
}

//file multi.TIF
$multiTIFF->writeImages('multi423432.gif', true); // combine all image into one single image

//files multi-0.TIF, multi-1.TIF, ...
$multiTIFF->writeImages('multi.gif', false);

?>
```

If you use only one gif, you can save it splitted on a folder, then merge separated images with a simple GD manipulation (one of the comments [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php)), and after use the code above to create the new Gif.